# Why can a constant count as an operator in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I've started with understanding the perturbation theory from Griffiths and I'm stuck on an example which is to find the first order correction in energies in case of infinite square well where the "floor" is raised to $V_0$. In the solution, they've declared $H' \text{(perturbed Hamiltonian)} = V_0$.
I was expecting the $H'$, being an operator, to have some $d/dx$ or some other operators like that but they have equalized an operator $(H')$ to a value ($V_0$). Can someone please clarify this for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$H'$ is the identity operator times $V_0$. Operators don't need to have $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$ in them, etc. They just need to be linear functions from vectors to vectors. This operator just happens to the be one that gives the same vector back, times a constant.

To be specific, given a quantum state $|\psi \rangle$ represented by a wave function $\psi(x)$, the action of $H'$ is
$$H' |\psi \rangle \rightarrow V_0 \psi(x) \, .$$
So $H'$ is an operator because it turned one quantum state into another.

Comment: That equation should probably be sth like $(H' \psi)(x) = V_0 \psi(x)$